# How to refresh an access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, refresh

I am building an MS Access application in which all the forms are modal. However, after data change in a form, I want to refresh the parent form of this form with newer data. Is there any way to do it. To elaborate further :

Consider there are two forms, Form A and Form B. Both are modal form. From Form A, I initiate Form B, and now Form B has the user attention. But at the close of form B, I want to refresh the Form A. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> No, it is like I want to run Form_Load
>   of Form A,if it is possible

-- Varun Mahajan

The usual way to do this is to put the relevant code in a procedure that can be called by both forms. It is best put the code in a standard module, but you could have it on Form a:

Form B:

```
Sub RunFormALoad()
   Forms!FormA.ToDoOnLoad
End Sub
```

Form A:

```
Public Sub Form_Load()
    ToDoOnLoad
End Sub    

Sub ToDoOnLoad()
    txtText = "Hi"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 11):

You can repaint and / or requery:

On the close event of form B:

```
Forms!FormA.Requery
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, it is like I want to run Form_Load of Form A,if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

"Requery" is indeed what you what you want to run, but you could do that in Form A's "On Got Focus" event. If you have code in your Form_Load, perhaps you can move it to Form_Got_Focus.

Comment: See Varun Mahajan's comment. Requery does not run the load events.

Comment: Which is why I suggested moving the code there to Form_Got_Focus (much like you did in your second answer). If he's wanting to refresh the data linked to the form, requery is the way to go.

Comment: If hew wants to re-do the Load event, move the code to another sub (just as Remou demonstrated) and then called it in the load and then in his refresh routing (either when closing B or when re-entring A with a Got_Focus). Got Focus will also work if A opens other windows too.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use `REQUERY` the specific combo box whose data you have changed AND that you do it after the `Cmd.Close` statement.  that way, if you were inputing data, that data is also requeried.

```
DoCmd.Close
Forms![Form_Name]![Combo_Box_Name].Requery
```

you might also want to point to the recently changed value

```
Dim id As Integer
id = Me.[Index_Field]
DoCmd.Close
Forms![Form_Name]![Combo_Box_Name].Requery
Forms![Form_Name]![Combo_Box_Name] = id
```

this example supposes that you opened a form to input data into a secondary table.

let us say you save School_Index and School_Name in a School table and refer to it in a Student table (which contains only the School_Index field).  while you are editing a student, you need to associate him with a school that is not in your School table, etc etc

Answer (score -2):

**to refresh the form you need to type -**
me.refresh
in the button event on click